# How can I attach element to bottom

Tags: html, css

I like designing website layout without javascript.
Just use CSS (if not necessary javascript)

ex) I like use CSS3 animation instead of jQuery animation.

And This is my problem.

I want to attach element `<footer>` to `<aside>`'s bottom
Also, footer should be go down if contents is big above footer like below code.

```js
var section = document.querySelector('aside section');
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  section.innerHTML += '<br/>Hi'
};
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; color: #fff; font-size: 16pt; }

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  
  background: #333;
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  
  background: #833;
}

aside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  
  background: #383;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 100px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

aside section {
  color: white;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  
  background: #338;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>
<main>
  Main<br>
  <button>Add Content to Aside</button>
</main>
<aside>
  <div class="wrap">
    <section>
      Aside Section
    </section>

    <footer>
      Footer
    </footer>
  </div>
</aside>
```

I think this is not bad. But, this code is work well when footer has fixed height.
However, The footer I'm trying to make doesn't have fixed height.

How can I make this?

---

I want to attach `<footer>` to bottom of `<aside>`.
However `<footer>` should be hide (can see after scroll) if the content of `<aside>` is big (height is big).

like below (but I want to without JS):

```js
var section = document.querySelector('aside section');
var footer = document.querySelector('aside footer');
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  section.innerHTML += '<br/>Hi'
};

section.style.paddingBottom = footer.offsetHeight + "px";
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; color: #fff; font-size: 16pt; }

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  
  background: #333;
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  
  background: #833;
}

aside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  
  background: #383;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

aside section {
  color: white;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
  background: #338;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>
<main>
  Main<br>
  <button>Add Content to Aside</button>
</main>
<aside>
  <div class="wrap">
    <section>
      1<br>
      2<br>
      3<br>
      4<br>
      5<br>
      6<br>
      7<br>
      8<br>
      9<br>
      10<br>
      11<br>
      12<br>
      13<br>
      14<br>
      16<br>
      17<br>
      18<br>
      19<br>
      20 will Not shown without JS
    </section>

    <footer>
      Not fixed height Footer
    </footer>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this?  [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqjLVz)

Comment: Your question is a bit vague could you be more clear?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. I will edit more clearly

Comment: @Leo I edited. If you fell vague also, please say me again.

Comment: I want to attach `<footer>` to bottom of `<aside>` like first snippet. but the first snippet should has `'fixed height' <footer>`.  
But, I need code work well where **not** `fixed height <footer>`.

Comment: @TaeSangCho I think your second snippet works fine even if you take the JS out. The footer is still at the bottom of the aside, it's just not as tall since you removed the fixed height. Is there an additional problem you need to solve?

Comment: @cjl750 the text `20 will Not shown without JS` was hidden by footer on second snippet (if without Javascript).

Comment: @TaeSangCho I see now. Couldn't tell at first because I'm looking at a desktop screen that is tall enough that all the content fit into the aside without any scrolling. But I see how the problem shows up when the screen is not tall enough. I've posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use display property to create this functionality by setting display of parent to display: table and the footer to display: table-row with a 1% height.

```
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; color: #fff; font-size: 16pt; }

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;

  background: #333;
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;

  background: #833;
}

aside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  height: auto;

  background: #383;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: table;
}

aside section {
  color: white;
  height: auto;
}

footer {
  background: #338;

  position: relative;
  display: table-row;
  height: 1%;
}
```

Here is a Demo:
[My Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqjLVz)

Hope it Helps! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [flex display](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) with automatic top margin on the footer to force it to the bottom of the container. Ensuring the container is at least as tall as the screen (as you're already doing) will therefore ensure the footer is at the bottom of the screen.

Here's the essential styles:

```
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
}
footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```css
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; color: #fff; font-size: 16pt; }

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: #333;
}
main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #833;
}
aside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #383;
}
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100%;
}
aside section {
  color: white;
}
footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  background: #338;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>
<main>
  Main<br>
  <button>Add Content to Aside</button>
</main>
<aside>
  <div class="wrap">
    <section>
      1<br>
      2<br>
      3<br>
      4<br>
      5<br>
      6<br>
      7<br>
      8<br>
      9<br>
      10<br>
      11<br>
      12<br>
      13<br>
      14<br>
      16<br>
      17<br>
      18<br>
      19<br>
      20 will Not shown without JS
    </section>
    <footer>
      Not fixed height Footer
    </footer>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: I like flex also, but I can't use this on production service (for browser support).
Thank you for your attention and answer